# Stop a service started with an AlarmManager

Tags: android, android-alarms

I am starting a service using `AlarmManager` which wakes up after 5 minutes and does some tasks, but I can't stop the service. How can I do this?

My code for starting the service:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SendDataService.class);  
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);  
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();  
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

// Wake up after 5 minutes
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000*60*5, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Why would be starting your service every 5 minutes, why not keep it running and send it data regularly ?

Comment: Not getting your point eamxple